# Easiest way to allow non-programmers to test WIP app

Tags: ios

I'm getting started in iOS app development, and I'm working with a musician and an artist.  They're both tech-savvy, but by no means programmers. I'd like to be able to let them test work-in-progress builds of the game.  What's the easiest way to do this?

After looking into it a bit, the options I see are the following, but I'm not really sure if these will work.  These artists are in another geo. This is a game built with the Unity engine, and will not run in the XCode iOS simulator.

1. Add their phones' ID's to my developer account and send them complete XCode projects, where all they should really need to do is plug in the phone and click Run.
2. Create an Archive of some kind and save it as a file that they can load using iTunes. I tinkered with this for an hour and couldn't get it to work.
3. Get an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, and create pseudo-official distributions of the app that they can download as if they were in my "enterprise".

Thanks for any tips you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com). I've used them and they're great. They simplify the entire process for you.

Comment: Or, if he doesn't want to use 3rd party services, he can use OTA: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html